# enable markdown syntax highlighting in code comments/docs

Tags: python, emacs, markdown, syntax-highlighting, restructuredtext

There are great in-code documentation standards for python, for example:

- [Google](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html)
- [Numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt)

Which use some nice, simple ReStructured / Markdown like syntax.  **Is there a way to have emacs render ReST / Md *inside* the comments of python code?**  I.e. the major-mode would still be python.el, and normal python syntax would work; but inside a comment block (`'''...'''` ) it would be rendered as some sort of markdown.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by using the `polymode` package (https://github.com/vspinu/polymode). It allows you to have multiple major modes in one buffer. Have a look at the screenshot examples.

There are other packages too which can enable multiple major modes in one file: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes